# One C# regex expression: allow only non-white space, and disallow only (&nbsp;)+

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0, regex-negation

I'm trying to validate that a user inputs some text into a rich text box, on the server side. I don't want to allow them to put in just HTML encoded spaces, either.  I'm using an application's built in regex validation, so I can't have more than one pattern.

Is it possible to use **only one** C# regex for the following pattern?

Allow (one or more non white space characters). Don't allow empty string:

```
^.*\S+.*$
```

-They need to enter some text. All white space not allowed:

```
!^\s+$
```

-Most likely white space will appear as `&nbsp;`. Don't allow a string of only HTML space characters:

```
!^(&nbsp;)+$
```

I thought that this would work but it doesn't:

```
 ^.*\S+$(!(^(\s+)+$))!(^(&nbsp;)+$)
```

So these two would be a valid strings:

```
'lorem ipsum' 
'lorem&nbsp;ipsum'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not clear on what you are trying to capture... but does this work?

```
^((\S(?<!&nbsp;))+((\s|&nbsp;)+)?)+$
```

Matches:
    `"lorem"`
    `"lorem ipsum"`
    `"lorem&nbsp;ipsum"`

Doesn't match:
    `""`
    `"   "`

*edited for comment*

Comment: You can use \S as the inverse of \s. Looks neater.

Comment: Whoa, neat! I did not know that existed.

Comment: @FlyingStreudel, I apologize but SO stripped out a lot of my question. A string of HTML encoded spaces, with nothing else, should *not* match the pattern.

Comment: @Hoppe try the new pattern

Comment: @FlyingStreudel This incorrectly matched an HTML encoded space followed by text. I.e. '[htmlSpace]lorem'. BUT, I removed the carat from the beginning of your string, and then it seems to be working. Thanks so much!!! Impressive. I'll do some more testing and then mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this would work fine (edited to match new requirements):

```
^\s*(?!&nbsp;)\S
```

Comment: I apologize but stack overflow stripped out a lot of my question. I tried to use more code tags to make it appear correctly. HTML encoded spaces should be allowed, but the string must consist of more than just HTML encoded spaces

Comment: @Hoppe - Ah, I see what you're trying to do now. Try the edited pattern.

Comment: @Hoppe - I was under the impression you wanted to treat `&nbsp;` the same as whitespace -- meaning allow it in the string, but block strings that are only whitespace and/or `&nbsp;`. Is that not what you want? Can you clarify your requirements?